# Chrome vertical scrollbar not working when URL has # at end

Tags: google-chrome, anchor

I've had an intermittent problem that I thought was due to un-cleared floats. What happens in Chrome (my main development browser) is the vertical scrollbar will lock in the top position and I cannot scroll down the page. Initially when the page starts to load it will allow you to scroll and then when the page is loaded it will jump back to the beginning and lock itself.

I've just been ripping apart my pages looking for un-cleared floats and missing tags and finally found out that it is due to a URL having a # at the end (which gets programatically added and remains when I refresh the page).

This issue only happens in chrome - does not appear to happen in other webkit browsers.

I assume its looking for an anchor and not finding it and then giving up. Its definitely a bug but was wondering about a workaround, or why it is only doing it on my site - I can't duplicate it for instance [here](http://shine.yahoo.com/channel/food/taste-test-ice-cream-sandwich-507442#).

**Shift click the URL to open in new browser**:

URL that will lock : [/faq#](http://www.rollingrazor.com/faq#)

URL that doesn't lock (same but without the #): [/faq](http://www.rollingrazor.com/faq)

Comment: I can't reproduce it with Chrome 2.0.172.43. The scroll bar work properly.

Comment: I am using Chrome 3.0.195.10 on Windows 7 and it very consistently breaks. i only just found out now it is due to #. I'm at starbucks now and everyone else is on mac, but I'll try to reproduce when I can!

Comment: I get this on multiple websites, hence I'm reading this post. I would say its a genuine chrome bug, most likely with the chrome event handler controller. (PID {root container}.exe)

Comment: hmm. havent seen this problem in a while. got new computer yesterday with fresh install of win 7 x64 with chrome 6.0.472.53 and just verified i can't duplicate it. which version are you on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For me, the solution was in a popup div's style: I had to make sure a div with a z-index and no float but surrounded by floating divs was given the style `float:none` and an explicit width (floating this was not needed as it was absolutely positioned). I have a thread working through this [here.](http://www.webmasterworld.com/html/4037285.htm)

Comment: thanks for this. thought i was alone. i've pretty much eliminated # by making sure to always return false - i'll try this out too though just in case i forgot one